# Why are rsa-sha2-512 and rsa-sha2-256 supported but not reported by ssh -Q key?

Tags: ssh, openssh

Running on macOS, I see these available key algorithms:

```
$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
$ ssh -Q key
ssh-ed25519
ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com
ssh-rsa
ssh-dss
ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
ecdsa-sha2-nistp384
ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com
ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com
ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com
ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com
ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com
```

The only RSA algorithms are `ssh-rsa` and `ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com`.

However, if I set this in my `.ssh/config`, there are no errors:

```
Host *
    HostKeyAlgorithms rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256
```

But supplying garbage doesn't work, so these algorithms must be supported:

```
Host *
    HostKeyAlgorithms foo
```

```
$ ssh whatever
/Users/scott/.ssh/config line 35: Bad key types 'foo'.
```

Why are the `rsa-sha2-512` and `rsa-sha2-256` algorithms supported but not reported by `ssh -Q key`? Are there any other hidden algorithms that are supported? Is there any way to find them other than searching the source?

Comment: wow... what are the odds that you asked this in the same hour I was looking for this. I found that removing ssh-rsa from the HostKeyAlgorithms also removes rsa-sha2-256 and rsa-sha2-512. I'm trying to find a way of disabling ONLY ssh-rsa (Ubuntu 18.04 - OpenSSH 7.6p1)

Comment: @JonathonAnderson: it shouldn't, and doesn't on my 18.04 test system; `ssh -vv -oHostKeyAlgorithms=-ssh-rsa` still offers both rsa-sha2 methods -- plus ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com which is just as insecure as ssh-rsa but has a different name. Maybe you should post a question about your problem, although superuser might be more suitable than here.

Comment: @dave_thomson_085 I think we're doing two different things. I was modifying sshd_config to change sshd server behavior. It looks like you're changing client behavior

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason is that `ssh -Q key` asks about key types, not signature types.

For most key types in SSH, there is but one signature type: `ecdsa-sha2-nistp384` will always use SHA-384, for example.  However, an RSA key, which has type `ssh-rsa`, can be used with one of three signature algorithms: SHA-1, which confusingly is also called `ssh-rsa`; SHA-256 (`rsa-sha2-256`); or SHA-512 (`rsa-sha2-512`).  The key type does not change, but the signature type does.

To determine signature types, you need `ssh -Q sig`, which, on my system with OpenSSH 8.4, prints the following:

```
ssh-ed25519
sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com
ssh-rsa
rsa-sha2-256
rsa-sha2-512
ssh-dss
ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
ecdsa-sha2-nistp384
ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com
webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com
```

Comment: And recent releasenotes warn OpenSSH plans to deprecate `ssh-rsa` _signature_ but not keytype since it is as you say used by other signatures; see e.g. http://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.7

Comment: This makes perfect sense! Thank you for the answer. It seems like `HostKeyAlgorithms` might be poorly named, and perhaps `man ssh_config` for that setting is incomplete, as `ssh -Q key` is mentioned there, but not `-Q sig`.

Comment: In the latest version, there is now `-Q HostKeyAlgorithms`, which if it is aliased properly might solve this confusion. https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#Q https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#HostKeyAlgorithms,